# Simple math coming out wrong

Tags: javascript, math

I've made a super simple script to pop out some hourly rates from a pool of tips. Thing is, this one specific result always comes out wrong. What the heck is going on?

```js
var tips = prompt('Enter final tips after payouts and cleaning');
   
//Hours worked for both positions
var tendHrsFirst = 11;
var tendHrsSecond = 10;  
   
//Hourly Rate   
var barThourly = ((tips/(tendHrsFirst+++tendHrsSecond)));

//This result here always comes out as if tendHrsFirst is 12 and not 11.   
var barToneTotal = (tendHrsFirst * barThourly);
 
//This result is always correct   
var barTtwoTotal = (tendHrsSecond * barThourly);
```

Comment: WTH do you think `+++` does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are incrementing with `tendHrsFirst++`, so it actually *is* 12.

I guess those are actually two commands.

`tendHrsFirst++` increments `tendHrsFrist` by 1. Afterwards, you add both numbers. Not sure why you think that's a good idea. Cleaning up your code should help avoiding such mistakes.

Comment: Should probably mention that since it is postfix ++, `tendHrsFirst` is 11 for the first equation, and afterwards it is 12, which is why `barTtwoTotal` is correct

Comment: Exactly. The operators `+` and `++` have different meanings. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought + would only place them next to each other and +++ would actually add them. I misunderstood my lesson! Very new, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

here

```
var barThourly = ((tips/(tendHrsFirst+++tendHrsSecond)));
```

you are using **+++** that means postfix increase of  **tendHrsFirst** and added to **tendHrsSecond**

or maybe 
prefix increase of **tendHrsSecond** added to **tendHrsFirst**

Comment: Concatenation is a string operation. In math, with numbers, we just call it addition :P

Comment: you are 100% right ... thanxs for the comment :)

Comment: This is actually a postfix operation on `tendHrsFirst` (not a prefix operation) due to [JavaScript operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).